# PDF template Checkbox using Send button Orbeon 4.10

Tags: pdf-generation, orbeon

I have a form with a checkbox control with 5 choices (non-exclusive). I have a PDF template configured according to the Orbeon documentation; the field is named correctly and export value set to `true`. I have verified this using the PDF button:

[image: Screenshot of a working PDF]

However when I use the *Send* button, the attached PDF I get does not have the required checkbox checked:

[image: No check]

Here is my *Send* button properties :

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.Neige.FLAH9-10">
    require-valid
    then email
    then save
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

Is it possible that the way the PDF is generated using the PDF button is different that when I use my own Send button? Is there a way to fix this on my end or is this a bug?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior ? @avernet

Comment: This looks like a bug. It should work the same in both cases, provided the data used to produce the PDF is the same in both cases. Can you send, privately if needed, an example of PDF template and form which exhibits this behavior?

Comment: You can see an example of the problem using this code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d7c649f0f86df9b4512 with this PDF : https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3swb0quywzeruh/Sans%20titre.pdf?dl=0 @ebruchez

Comment: https://imgur.com/bqlabxw see result here. thanks

Comment: @ebruchez i have also tried this in a brand new vanilla Tomcat/orbeon 4.10.1 installation. same issues

Comment: Please advise on this situation ? Is there anything I can do to fix this? I tried enabling debug logging but I'm not seeing any error in the log. @ebruchez

Comment: I will look at it but probably not before Monday.

Comment: I just got to try this and it works as expected with your form and your Sans titre.pdf. I used the same `send` process you pasted above, and I get the correct PDF by email. I tried setting both checkboxes, or only one of them. So something else is awry.

Comment: @ebruchez Sorry for the long delay, my PDF are still not working as expected. The PDF button work ok but the Email button does not fill the checkbox. Any way you could take a look at my issues?

Comment: Since I did try to reproduce the issue back in December but couldn't, doc you have an idea for a next step? Maybe an Orbeon WAR including everything?